# Eigenvalues of correlation matrix which have the form of an harmonic function

Tags: fourier-transform, linear-systems, correlation, statistics, linear-algebra

As a continuation to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/how-do-i-calculate-the-eigenvalues-of-a-covariance-matrix-which-contains-harmoni), I took the matrix $C_{2 \times 2}$ which is:

$$C=\left[
    \begin{array}{}
      a& ace^{-\frac{|\phi_1-\phi_2|}{2}}\\
      ace^{-\frac{|\phi_1-\phi_2|}{2}} & a    
    \end{array}
\right] $$

And I found its eigenvector and eigenvalues which are:

$$v_1 = \left[
    \begin{array}{}
      1 \\
      1    
    \end{array}
\right]
,v_2 = \left[
    \begin{array}{}
      -1 \\
      1    
    \end{array}
\right] \\ \lambda_1 = a+ace^{-\frac{|\phi_1-\phi_2|}{\rho}},\lambda_2 = a-ace^{-\frac{|\phi_1-\phi_2|}{\rho}} 
 $$

So, it is still not clear to me why the author says that the eigenvectors have the form $e^{in\phi_i}$.

This form doesn't even have the shape of a vector, and I specifically found the eigenvectors, and there isn't any complex component in it.

[image]

Comment: It's absolutely necessary that you put the correct citation for the article you're including here. That's not optional.

Comment: Also, you're still clinging to words. The Eigenvectors you found at least have values from an equidistant sampling of complex oscillations.

Comment: Also, this is **still** the same question, you even note that. "It's still not clear" is not a valid reason to open a new question, if you don't really ask a new question.

Comment: I agree with @MarcusMüller here: you haven't found an answer to you original question yet, so expand on that question and get an answer that you can accept.